# Accessing address of the pointer in a C struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct test {
   int **x;
}
```

How can I access address of the pointer x?

**SOLVED**

```
int main () {
   struct test * mytest = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
   ...
   printf("Address of the pointer x: %zu", &my_test->x); 
}
```

Comment: `x` is a pointer field, so is already an address. `&x_tmp` is the address of the local `x_tmp` pointer.

Comment: printf("Address pointed by x: %p",  x_tmp);

Comment: `mytest->x = 5;` not really good value for a pointer :/ and besides you're trying to access `x` field before actually allocating memory for `mytest` itself

Comment: I did a bit of confusion. What I wanted was exactly the address of the pointer of a pointer of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be a bit confused. An `int *` is already an address, so in that case you could just use `my_test->x` (note that your application would segfault right away, since `struct test *my_test` doesn't point to anything).

If you want the **address of the pointer** (that would be an `int **`), you'd simply do `&my_test->x`.

Also it seems odd that you're assigning the `int *` to `5`; that's a bit of a strange memory address. Perhaps you want to set the `int` at the location `x` to `5`? In that case you'd write `*my_text->x = 5`.

Note that it's dangerous dereferencing pointers that don't point to anything sensible. You haven't assigned any pointers in your code, so they might just (they probably will) point to crap.

Comment: I did a bit of confusion. What I wanted was exactly the address of the pointer of a pointer of pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is meaningless :

```
x_tmp = mytest->x;
printf("Address pointed by x: %zu", &x_tmp);
```

It just prints the address of the `x_tmp` variable whatever is contained in `mytest` and in mytest->x`.

Comment: I did a bit of confusion. What I wanted was exactly the address of the pointer of a pointer of pointer.